# Getting Base Station Information in Android

Tags: android, geolocation, locationmanager, cellid

Is there anyway to get the base station and/or cellId information of the subscriber in Android?

Answer (score 2):

here is a good code snipplet for your problem:

http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/11/29/android-access-cell-phone-details-cell-id-lac-signal-strength/

Comment: PhoneStateIntentReceiver has been removed from Android SDK. We can't use the given code sample.